# How to put two or more values from two columns in a database table into a <datalist> value attribute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database

I have a dropdown select datalist needs to contain the value combination from 2 columns in a database table.

I was tried this way:

```
function AttendCourseSelect({courses}) {

    const courseName = {course.name} + "-" + {course.level};

    return (
        <div className="col-sm col-md col-lg">
            <label htmlFor="CourseName">Course: </label>
            <input type="text" list="courses"/>
            <datalist id="courses">
                {courses.map(((course) => {
                    return <option value={courseName} />
                }))}
            </datalist>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AttendCourseSelect;
```

But the `courseName` syntax is not correct here.
Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `{}` when accessing/using values out side of `return`.

`const courseName = course.name + "-" + course.level;`

or you could use Template literals (Template strings)

```
const courseName = `${course.name}-${course.level}`;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm a newbie, not very proficient in using some expressions, your answer helps me a lot.
After I can have the dropdown menu present the desired value (the names), I got another problem. The values in the <datalist> are names, but I need to post the `id` to the database only as the table only asks the `id ` as the foreign key. Could you hint me how to get relevant `id` as I select the `name` in the value?

Comment: you can use uuid package and generate a random Id and pass it to the db, but I suggest you talk to the maintainers the db on how&what to pass as the id